# How can I use Number() to convert a string to number without losing the decimal points?

Tags: javascript

I tried

```
num = 0.5;
num =  Number(num.toPrecision(2));
```

I want the result to be 0.50, but it's returning 0.5.

Comment: 0.5 and 0.50 are the same thing. They are the same number. You can output them as strings with different decimal places, but you're dealing with Number here

Comment: You're converting your number to a string then back to a number. toPrecision returns a string. You then pass that to the Number constructor to get a number again. There's no need to do that. Ditch the number constructor if all you want is a string representation with the appropriate precision.

Answer (score 2):

The `.toPrecision()` method returns a string representation of a number. If you pass that to `Number()`, it parses it as a number and you get a number value as a result. The number `0.5` and the number `0.50` are precisely equal; when you print or log the number `0.5` you don't get any extra digits because that's just how the *default* string conversion of numbers works. That, in fact, is the reason `.toPrecision()` exists.

The nature of JavaScript numbers is such that it just doesn't make sense to want to retain trailing fractional zero digits. Numbers are binary floating point values internally, so trailing *decimal* fractional digits have no place.